# Ember observer fires on array controller when it shouldn't

Tags: ember.js

#### Update

Here's a bin of my problem: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ruwet/8/edit?html,js,console,output4

---

I have a simple filtered property on an array controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  activeEncodes: function() {
    return this.filterBy('model', 'isActive');
  }.property('model.@each.isActive');

});
```

I'm connected to a websocket and am updating encodes in my store with

```
store.store.push('encode', data);
```

Even though it's just updating a certain property on my data (`progress`), `activeEncodes` is being recalculated. This is causing some visual jank in my templates.

If I use `model.@each.id`, it doesn't recalculate, but any other property seems to trigger the CP to recalculate (even if that property is not changing).

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

When you push it causes the entire model to invalidate. This is then considered a new model which fires any observers watching anything on that model (since it sees it as a new model).  It's tangentially related to [Ember data model reload causes item in {{each}} to be removed/inserted back - losing current state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087282/ember-data-model-reload-causes-item-in-each-to-be-removed-inserted-back-lo) as well.

`id` is likely a special case, I believe it lives outside of the scope of the underlying properties on the model (same reason you don't define the id on the model).  I'm just guessing on that though.

Comment: what a bummer. Is there another way to update a model that doesn't invalidate the whole thing?

Comment: I'm confused because doesn't RESTAdapater use push too?